# How to select lines containing specified keywords using the WHERE…LIKE statement in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

I want to select lines containing one of the strings specified by the vector keyWords in the “index_name“ column. The items of keyWords are not fixed. The following is my script:

```
keyWords = ['Charging pile','Charging']
tbIndexBasicInfoDemo = select *  from tbIndex where or (like(index_name, stringFormat("%i%",keyWords[0])),like(index_name, stringFormat("%i%",keyWords[1])))
```

However, an error occurs: `stringFormat(format, [args...]). : invalid format for %`. How to modify my script?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate strings with placeholders as follows:

```
tbIndex=table(["Charging pile 1","Pile 2"] as index_name)
keyWords = ['Charging pile','Charging']
select * from tbIndex 
where rowOr(each(like{index_name,}, "%"+keyWords+"%"))
```